# Stop refreshing search bar on an image slider when it slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, search, uislider

`enter code here`I'm using data-live search bar on an image slider. But it automatically refreshes while searching when image slides. So user have to start search again after a image slides.

[image]

Code I have used

```
<div id="myFormDiv" style="margin-top:-30%;">
        <form action="" method="get" id="myForm" name="myForm">
            <div class="col-md-9"
            style="color:gray;background:white;opacity:0.9;padding-top: 1px;padding-bottom:2px;height:100%;">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h5>Destination</h5>
                <div class="section_room" id='countryNew' style='color:#849288'>
                    <select data-live-search="true" id='country' name='destination'
                    style='cursor: pointer;color:#849288;height:35px; width: 100%;'
                    class='selectpicker frm-field required'>
                    <option selected disabled style='color:#849288'>-please select-</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($dest_details as $value) {
                        echo "<option style='color:#849288;' value='" . $value->destination_id . "'";
                        if ($des_id == $value->destination_id) {
                            echo "selected";
                        }
                        echo ">" . $value->destination_name . "</option>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
   </form>
```

Can anyone help me with this.Is there anyway to avoid this.

Comment: do you have some code you can provide?

Comment: Sure i ll update the problem @NevilleNazerane